# Laravel Error - Trying to get property game of non-object

Tags: laravel

I am trying to run a query that counts the number of times a user participate in an event, but I got this error:

> Trying to get property 'game' of non-object

Also this was underlined:

```html
<td><?php echo e($player->game); ?></td>
```

I have written the query

Controller

```php
$players = DB::table("played_game")
    ->select("played_game.user_id","played_game.game","users.username", DB::raw("COUNT(played_game.game) as no_game"))
    ->join("users","users.id","=","played_game.user_id")
    ->groupBy("played_game.game","users.username","played_game.user_id")
    ->orderByRaw('COUNT(played_game.game) DESC')
    ->paginate(15);
```

View

```html
@foreach ($players as $key => $player_list)
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3"
            style="background-color: #F7F7F7">{{ $player_list->username }}</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($player_list as $player)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $player->game }}</td>
            <td>{{ $player->no_game }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I want to display the player(username) involved in colspan and other details in the td.

Comment: because `$players` is empty?

Comment: No. $players is not empty

Comment: can you dump `$players` value?

Comment: `$player` isn't what you think it is. It may be a string or something else, but it isn't an object, so you can't access properties. Perhaps do a `dd($player)` in that loop.

Comment: is `$player_list` an array?

Answer (score 0):

`paginate()` returns an instance of `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` which extends the `AbstractPaginator` that has functions like `items()`, check it out for further useful functions.

To get the paginated result, do `->paginate(15)->items()`, you can also do `all()`, `toArray()`, `toJson()` and other stuff since it implements a number of interfaces.

Comment: also, fun fact.. when doing a `foreach($paginatedResult as $p) { echo $p }` you seem to get the page navigation pane as html